# calling display method for int array from main method

Tags: java

I have one one class LargeInteger:

```
public class LargeInteger {

    private int[] intArray;

    public LargeInteger(String s) { 

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            intArray[i] = Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 10);
        }
    }

    public void display() {

         for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
                System.out.print(intArray[i]);


            }

        }
}
```

Hopefully This is taken a string and converting it into an int array.. I am not sure I did this right yet but that is not my question yet.

In my main method I am trying to call the display method:

Main:

```
string1 = input.next(); 
LargeInteger firstInt = new LargeInteger(string1);
System.out.printf ("First integer: %s \n", firstInt.display());
```

Because my display method is void this does not work, But I am not sure what to make it return.. if anything? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Your `display` method is printing the value directly. Instead you want to build a `String`  and then return that.

---

I suggest you start with just returning a constant string. When that works, try to create the string on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your `display()` method you have this:

```
System.out.print(intArray[i]);
```

which would print a single digit.

Instead, you could change the method to:

```
public String display() {
  StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i : intArray) {     
    number.append(i);        
  }
  return number.toString();
}
```

Note that I used a `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation. That yields better performance for really large numbers, since with plain concatenation each iteration would create two new `String` instances and this would quickly eat up memory and processing time.

**Edit**: Just fixed a typo in the code and simplified the loop using for each.

Comment: That looks nice and is good to know. I will not be using it for this homework assignment but I do appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two things which come to my mind you could do:

1. Use the class `BigInteger` as it does exactly what you want.
2. Change your `display` method to return a String - I suggest you use a StringBuilder to create it:

   ```
   public String display() {
     final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
       result.append(intArray[i]);
     }
     return result.toString();
   }
   ```

Also I would suggest not to call the member variable `intArray` as this is already contained in the type information of it. Better call it `value` or `contents` or something more related to its usage.

Comment: I'll change the name. Appreciate the help. using the BigInteger class is forbidden for this assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You display method actually prints to the screen. All you need to do is change your code to:

```
string1 = input.next(); 
LargeInteger firstInt = new LargeInteger(string1);
System.out.println ("First integer:");
firstInt.display();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a String:

```
public String display() {           
  String result="";
  for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {     
    // create string representation
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your display method should return a String.

```
    public String display() {

        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {  

             temp = temp + intArray[i].ToString();
        }

        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Since the method doesn't display but returns a String, I'd suggest you overwrite the ToString() Method of your LargeInteger Class.